# Book(s) for text embedding

Tags: natural-language-processing, reference-request, word-embedding, books, vector-semantics

Text here refers to either character or word or sentence.

Is there any recent **textbook** that encompasses from classical methods to the modern techniques for embedding texts?

If a single textbook is unavailable then please recommend a list of books covering the whole spectrum as mentioned above.

Modern textbooks that are similar to [Christopher D. Manning, Prabhakar Raghavan and Hinrich Schütze, Introduction to Information Retrieval, Cambridge University Press. 2008](https://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/information-retrieval-book.html) are highly encouraged.

[This question](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/20911/is-there-a-good-book-or-paper-on-word-embeddings) asks for textbook/research paper on word embedding only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I propose you try [this](http://web.stanford.edu/%7Ejurafsky/slp3/ed3book_dec302020.pdf). It's about modern Natural Language Processing, Computational Linguistics and Speech Recognition, including Embeddings methods.

Comment: Yeah. Chapter 6: Vector Semantics and Embeddings is apt.

Comment: Yeah, answer is useful. But I am waiting for a book that explicitly dedicates on that topic.

Comment: To find a book that explicitly focuses on embeddings, I think it is something very difficult. My proposal, however, provides a strong theoretical background for this topic.

Answer (score 1):

Having a sound understanding on language processing will help you understand all its concepts. [This](https://towardsdatascience.com/top-nlp-books-to-read-2020-12012ef41dc1) summarise must reads for NLP.